# Intel's Trusted Execution Technology (TXT): enable in BIOS or not?

Tags: bios, virtualization

I have a new Dell 7530 mobile workstation that I just started configuring.

This machine uses an [Intel Xeon E-2186M](https://ark.intel.com/products/134859/Intel-Xeon-E-2186M-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-4-80-GHz-) and has 32 GB of ECC DRAM.  This CPU fully supports the latest hardware virtualization technologies (VT-x, VT-d, EPT).

Initially this machine will be running Windows 10 due to lack of time to switch operating systems.  I really hope to have time in about a year to invest in switching to Linux, as I hate the Bea$t's new spyware as a service business model.  I certainly will be running Linux virtual machines on it in the interim.

One of my first steps was to go into its BIOS and pour thru all the settings.  I was pleased to see that Dell's defaults were mostly good, only a few changes were needed.  For example, it was default configured for Secure Boot.

In its Virtualization Support section, they enabled both "Intel Virtualization Technology" (VT-x) and "VT for Direct I/O" (VT-d) by default, which is also good.

However, there was a 3rd option for Intel's Trusted Execution Technology (TXT) that was disabled.  I think that the BIOS description said this:

> This option specifies whether a Measured Virtual Machine Monitor
>   (MVMM) can utilize the additional hardware capabilities provided by
>   Intel Trusted Execution Technology. The TPM Virtualization Technology,
>   and Virtualization technology for direct I/O must be enabled to use
>   this feature.
>
> Trusted Execution - disabled by default.

I say "think" because the [official Dell documentation for the 7530's BIOS](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/precision-15-7530-laptop/precision_7530_setup_specifications/virtualization-support?guid=guid-f1e2bb39-92bd-4afd-a233-10616d00ccbe&lang=en-us), as of today, does not not mention that option.  The text above is for the [Dell Latitude E7470](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/latitude-e7470-ultrabook/late_e7470_om/virtualization-support-screen-options?guid=guid-e4a6f62c-5c11-498c-bacd-6bb8bee4c097&lang=en-us), altho it is what I recall my BIOS saying.

From that description, plus [Intel's whitepaper](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/trusted-execution-technology/trusted-execution-technology-security-paper.html), it sounds like something that I would want to enable, since I for sure will be using VirtualBox (and in the future, something more powerful like KVM or Xen).  Unfortunately, a web search found no endorsements for that theory.

Instead, all I have found is several reports saying to turn off, especially on Dell systems, for both VirtualBox and KVM: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746462/error-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disa), [link 2](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#.22KVM:_disabled_by_BIOS.22_error).  (My original question put more links in here, but when I tried to submit, this website claimed that my question was spam...)

Does anyone know the definitive answer?

I note that some of the links saying not to enable it go back several years, so perhaps it was once true advice that now is no longer valid?

Comment: Does your processor even support VT-d?  Update your question to include this vital information

Comment: If using Linux, also post the output if cat proc/cpuinfo - this should have an appropriate flag set if it's enables (TXT I think)

Comment: @Ramhound: you are right, I should have mentioned that, question updated as requested.

Comment: @davidgo: question edited: Win 10 for now, Linux in the future.

Comment: I very much doubt VirtualBox makes any use of TXT.

Answer (score -1):

I think this option should be enabled.

I had it disabled and I want to check if IOMMU is enabled.

Of course I append `intel_iommu=on` parameter to `/etc/default/grub` and update grub and reboot system before.

It gave me an error from my graphic card when I issued a command:

`dmesg | grep -E (”DMAR | IOMMU”)` it gave me 2 lines:

```
DMAR: IOMMU enabled

DMAR: BIOS has allocated no shadow GTT; disabling IOMMU for graphics.
```

So IOMMU for my graphic card was disabled. Then I set "Intel Trusted Execution Technology" in BIOS to enabled and now the command:

`dmesg | grep -E (”DMAR | IOMMU”)`produced the output:

```
[    0.057735] ACPI: DMAR 0x00000000CA9B0718 0000B8 (v01 INTEL  CP_DALE  00000001 INTL 00000001)

[    0.417895] DMAR: IOMMU enabled

[    0.504475] DMAR: Host address width 36

[    0.504476] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x0

[    0.504483] DMAR: dmar0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 1:0 cap c9008020e30272 ecap 1000

[    0.504484] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed91000 flags: 0x0*

[    0.504487] DMAR: dmar1: reg_base_addr fed91000 ver 1:0 cap c0000020230272 ecap 1000

[    0.504488] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed93000 flags: 0x1

[    0.504493] DMAR: dmar2: reg_base_addr fed93000 ver 1:0 cap c9008020630272 ecap 1000

[    0.504494] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000ca971000 end: 0x000000ca985fff

[    0.504496] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000cdc00000 end: 0x000000cfffffff

[    1.635058] DMAR: Disabling batched IOTLB flush on Ironlake

[    2.201405] DMAR: No ATSR found

[    2.201519] DMAR: dmar1: Using Register based invalidation

[    2.201541] DMAR: dmar0: Using Register based invalidation

[    2.201568] DMAR: dmar2: Using Register based invalidation
[    2.201599] DMAR: Setting RMRR:

[    2.201821] DMAR: Setting identity map for device 0000:00:02.0 [0xcdc00000 - 0xcfffffff]

[    2.202736] DMAR: Setting identity map for device 0000:00:1a.0 [0xca971000 - 0xca985fff]

[    2.202898] DMAR: Setting identity map for device 0000:00:1d.0 [0xca971000 - 0xca985fff]

[    2.202941] DMAR: Prepare 0-16MiB unity mapping for LPC

[    2.203069] DMAR: Setting identity map for device 0000:00:1f.0 [0x0 - 0xffffff]

[    2.233832] DMAR: Intel(R) Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O

[   14.362393] [drm] DMAR active, disabling use of stolen memory
```

I think now IOMMU is active. Hope this helps you to decide.

Comment: This does not imply TXT needs to be enabled. It implies your BIOS is broken. It’s great that enabling TXT fixes it, but that’s just a side-effect.